# Bring markers to front using Leaflet.js and Google maps (Google.js)

Tags: google-maps, openstreetmap, leaflet

I'm using Leaflet with google maps plugin [(Google.js)](https://github.com/shramov/leaflet-plugins/blob/master/layer/tile/Google.js), but the google maps layer is always in front of the markers.

```js
   var map = new L.Map('map', {center: new L.LatLng(51.51, -0.11), zoom: 9});
   var googleLayer = new L.Google('ROADMAP');
   map.addLayer(googleLayer);

  L.marker([-32.69, -62.10]).addTo(map)
            .bindPopup('A pretty CSS3 popup. <br> Easily customizable.')
            .openPopup();
```

This loads the markers first and inmediatly loads the map, hiding the markers behind.
If I delete the HTML node containing the tiles, I can see a grey background and the markers.

Comment: searching the web I've found this http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/44598/leaflet-google-map-baselayer-markers-not-visible